# К какому типу относится предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

К какому типу односоставных вы отнесли бы предложение: 
По бороде Авраам, а по делам Хам?

Answer (score 6):

Я отнес бы это предложение не к односоставным, а к неполным, которые считаются двусоставными. Мотивация: "По бороде (он есть, был, будет) Авраам" (то же относится и ко второй части предложения). Здесь отсутствует подлежащее "он" и глагол-связка от именного сказуемого. Отсутствующие члены предложения восстанавливаются по смыслу, а это признак неполного предложения. (Пример из Розенталя: На небе облака, как розовые перышки).
Если же настаивать на односоставном предложении, то тогда, естественно, назывное предложение, хотя мне это совсем не нравится

Answer (score 1):

По бороде Авраам, а по делам Хам. Конечно , это неполные двусоставные предложения.В первом предложении есть группа  сказуемого (дополнение "по бороде"), и во  втором то же самое ( дополнение "по делам") А если есть дополнения, то никак мы  не можем  отнести  эти предложения к назывным  односоставным. В назывном  предложении может  быть только ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ( группа  подлежащего)
Ранний  вечер.Тысячи километров трудного пути. Волшебная  сила искусства.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, назывное предложение может иметь разные второстепенные члены. В нем нет только сказуемого. Да и по Вашим примерам видно, что здесь есть дополнения.

Comment: В моих  примерах назывных предложений есть только ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ, согласованные и несогласованные.
 Тысячи километров --подлежащее. Тысячи километров чьи? пути--несогласованное определение. Пути какого? трудного.  Сила-подлежащее. Сила  какая? волшебная--согласованное определение. Сила чья? искусства--несогласованное определение. Как видим, это чистой воды назывные предложения,в которых есть главный член  предложения--подлежащее и определения.
От существительного или другой части речи, заменяющей  ее(местоимения), мы задаем вопросы определения. Сила чего? искусства--грубая синтаксическая ошибка.